# MySQL Explain vs Slow Log

Tags: mysql, performance, explain

Using MySQL (5.1.66) explain says it will scan just 72 rows while the "slow log" reports the whole table was scanned (Rows_examined: 5476845)
How is this possible? I can't figure out what's wrong with the query

`*name*` is a string unique index and 
`*date*` is just a regular int index

This is the EXPLAIN
`EXPLAIN SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE  name LIKE 'The%Query%'
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 3;`

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      table   index   name            date    4       NULL    72      Using where
```

Output from Slow Log

`# Query_time: 5.545731  Lock_time: 0.000083 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 5476845
SET timestamp=1360007079;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'The%Query%' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3;`

Answer (score 4):

The `rows` value that is returned from an `EXPLAIN` is an *estimate* of the number of rows that have to be examined to find results that match your query.

If you look, you will see that the key being chosen for the query execution is `date`, which is probably being picked because of your `ORDER BY` clause.  Because the key being used in the query is unrelated to your `WHERE` clause, that's probably why the estimate is getting messed up.  Even though your `WHERE` clause is doing a `LIKE` on the `name` column, the optimizer may decide not to use an index at all:

> Sometimes MySQL does not use an index, even if one is available. One
>   circumstance under which this occurs is when the optimizer estimates
>   that using the index would require MySQL to access a very large
>   percentage of the rows in the table. (In this case, a table scan is
>   likely to be much faster because it requires fewer seeks.) [source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html)

In short, the optimizer is choosing not to use the `name` key, even though it would be the one that is the limiting factor of rows to be returned.  You can try [forcing the index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html) to see if that improves the performance.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Using a FORCE INDEX on `name` is making most queries faster. But I still need the `date` index to make sure if the index is too big to select the latest (e.g. the% is big, and last ones would make it faster). Doing a FORCE INDEX on both makes the query as slow as no FORCE INDEX.